# Adding User input to a Json file C# - Error

Tags: c#, json

I am running my segment which is suppose to read the input from the form and add it into the json file.

This is the form input layout - If the radio button "Custom" is selected, then the user is required to enter the width and height values into the box. these inputs are then pull to add to a json
[image: Form Layout]

The problem i am experiencing is the error i get when i run my code - See code below:

```
    //Dialog Size Setup
    if (CustomSize.Checked)
    {
        string widthBox = Width.Text.ToString();
        string heightBox = Height.Text.ToString();

        string CustomSizejson = File.ReadAllText(DownloadConfigFilelocation);
        JObject CustomSizeobj = JObject.Parse(CustomSizejson);
        CustomSizeobj["externalSite"]["webLogin"]["window"] = "height=" + heightBox + ",width=" + widthBox + ",resizable,scrollbars";
        string CustomSizenewJson = CustomSizeobj.ToString();
        File.WriteAllText(DownloadConfigFilelocation, CustomSizenewJson);
    }
```

This is the error I get

[image: SEE ERROR HERE]

Can some assist?

Comment: It's impossible to help without the Json string itself. Most likely one of the properties specified there is missing: externalSite, webLogin or window.

Comment: If the `externalSite` and `webLogin` objects are missing you'll have to *add* them. The indexer won't create missing objects.